# Comparison of 2 Nested Tables Will Not Compile

Tags: oracle, plsql

The idea here is to build a nested table, then load a second nested table from a PL/SQL query and compare the two in one go:

```
Package Body ...
  Procedure Definition ...
    Cursor cX is
      select * from some_table;
    Type tcX is table of cX%ROWTYPE;
    rsOldData tCX;
    rsNewData tCX;
    ... load rsNewData with data ...
    Open cX;
    Fetch cX bulk collect into rsOldData;
    close cX;
    if rsOldData != rsNewData then
      ... do something ...
    end if;
bla, bla, bla, end everything else
```

The problem is, the comparison of the two nested tables will not compile.  I've tried both equate and not equate, so it's not the symbology.

I will try creating the type as a standalone type and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You say that your code "will not compile" but you don't tell us the compilation error, what line the error is thrown on, etc.  Without that, it's hard to guess at the error.  Definitionally, what do you consider "equal"?  Are you talking about set-based equality (i.e. the set (1,2,3) is equivalent to the set (3,2,1) because they contain the same elements) or do you want to consider the index of the element in the collection as well?  Do you want to ignore duplicates?

Comment: You can use set operations, but your collections must be database objects, so you can query them like tables.

Comment: Sorry - the error is Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'tcX'

Comment: The two nested tables need to be equal in such a way that for each record in "A" there is a matching record in "B".

Comment: Are you saying that you want to do a set-based comparison?  So the set (1,2,3) is equivalent to the set (3,2,1)?  Or do you care about order?  I'm not sure what "matching record" means to you.

Comment: Matching record means that if I have a record with data in several fields in nested table "A", I will have a record in nested table "B" with the same data in those fields.  However, I'm thinking that this type of comparison is only valid for simple nested tables, that is, nested tables with only one field.

Comment: Order is not that important.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer.  According to "Using PL/SQL Collection with SQL Statements":

> Comparing Records
>
> > Records cannot be tested for nullity or compared for equality or inequality ...

I guess that pretty much sinks that.